# Android binding double value to view using string resources

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Trying to bind double value to view using string resources.

**Attempt 1:**

layout.xml

```
android:text="@{@string/user_popularity(Double.toString(user.popularity))}"
```

string.xml

```
<string name="user_popularity">Popularity: %s</string>
```

**Attempt 2:**

layout.xml

```
android:text="@{String.format(@string/user_popularity, user.popularity)}"
```

string.xml

```
<string name="user_popularity">Popularity: %.1f</string>
```

**Error:**

```
Error:(167, 107) error: double cannot be dereferenced
```

*Here are some similar questions*

1. [How do I format a double using Android view data bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562093/how-do-i-format-a-double-using-android-view-data-bindings)
2. [How do I use databinding to combine a string from resources with a dynamic variable in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978499/how-do-i-use-databinding-to-combine-a-string-from-resources-with-a-dynamic-varia)

Comment: Did you have difficulty when you followed the answers? They look like they answer your question and your attempts don't use them.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both the solution from the mention links.

Comment: This should work: `android:text="@{@string/user_popularity(user.popularity)}"` and the string resource `<string name="user_popularity">Popularity: %1$f</string>` assuming that user.popularity is a `double` or `float`. What are you seeing? Is it compile-time error, a runtime exception, or is the formatting wrong? It could be that you haven't assigned a user using `binding.setUser()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it was quite simple, my bad I was doing the wrong way.
Here's the solution.

```
<string name="user_popularity">Popularity: %.1f</string>
android:text="@{@string/user_popularity(user.popularity)}"
```